# JQuery click after propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, telerik

I have searched high and low for an answer to this. I know there is a way to **stop** propagation when triggering a click event, but is there a way to run the click event code **after** propagation.

The reason I ask is, I have a telerik RadTabStrip that is built up dynamically on the server. In each tab page is a map which has markers on it indicating where people sit in the office. I need to get a handle on the first marker when the user clicks a tab, but the problem I have is the marker element is not part of the DOM until **after** the click has propagated.

```
$('.tab').click(function(e){

   // e.continuePropagation(); ?? or something?

   var markerTop = $('.cardiff').offSet().top; // Is always 0 even though the marker is 243 px from the top

}):
```

The reason I am not using the telerik client api is because I am inside a couple of JQuery AJAX `success` functions and am unsure of how it will behave.

**EDIT:**
I have solved my problem using another AJAX call, but I am still keen to know whether there is a way to get the default to run before the code in the click event

Comment: You could opt to use a `setTimeout`, but that will be quite unstable. Best thing to do, is to hook into the ajax success call when loading the tab contents instead of the click of a tab.

Comment: Yeah, I did think about the `setTimeout` but quickly decided against it. I will look into the ajax call, but I don't think the tab click calls ajax to load the page.

Comment: Ah I see, the marker element is added on click, however it's position is decided the result of an ajax call no? If there are no Ajax calls whatsoever, then setTimeout will be a good option, since the event you need is afterClick, which is non-existent.

Comment: It is now, that's how I got around it.

Comment: Ok, so the element is live after the ajax call, any means to hook into the success call? Does it use jQuery?

Comment: If the ajax call for the marker position is done with jQuery, you could look into http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: I have solved my issue thanks. I am just curious whether it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by clicking on the Tab it AJAX's in some content or otherwise with your markers in it you need to put a callback in that code not in the click event of the tab.

I can't think of way to get hold of content which isn't yet part of the DOM in the click event callback.

Looking at the TabStrip Documentation you just want to use the [OnClientTabSelected](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip-client-side-events.html) event surely? You mention that you are doing some custom Ajax calls but perhaps these could be moved inside of the pre-built telerik events?

Comment: That's my problem. I don't want to prevent the default. I want the default to happen first.

Comment: That's actually what he is *not* looking for, or am I misreading the question?

Comment: @Mark Perry, I would mark this as an answer but the `event.preventDefault()` bit is not part of the answer.

Comment: Edited my answer to remove the redundant part.

Answer (score 1):

-> http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I did look at using this in some way but I could think of how. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$('.tab').click(function(e){

   // e.continuePropagation(); ?? or something?

   setTimeout(function(){var markerTop = $('.cardiff').offSet().top;},0);

}):
```

The function in the setTimeout call will be invoked after the current thread execution, which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So if you need to fire an event when an element enters the DOM (i guess that is your problem because your markers enter the DOM after the click event) you could take a look at the [livequery](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-create-event/) plugin. It's an old plugin but it alllows you to attach and manipulate lements as soon as they are created (in this way you might be able to get their position!)